# How to use xlarge tag while minsdk is 8

Tags: android

I have the following manifest file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.propertymanager"
    android:versionCode="6"
    android:versionName="4.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />

    <supports-screens 
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"    
        />
```

I have min sdk set to 8 which is v2.2 while target sdk set to 15 and I am building against Api 8. The problem that this is giving me error in the xml because xlarge screen is not recognized.
If I build my project against api 15 then the error disappears. However, won't the devices running API 8 (v2.2) crash or fail because they wont recognize the xlarge screen tag?
Any solution?

Comment: I may be wrong. But older devices should ignore any attributes they don't understand. (XML - EXTENSIBLE markup language). you should be able to keep Min version to 8 and target 15, without any issues.

Comment: Madhusan is correct. The app won't crash. It's recommended to build your app with the latest API.

Answer (score 0):

## Weird.

Devices ignore attributes they don't understand. `AndroidManifest` needs to be a valid XML of course with a few compulsory tags like the `application` tag in the file.

#### Things that could address the problem:

- Update ADT
- Do a `Project -> Clean`